# Query is taking much longer to execute

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query to get the total score, steps, and cycling based on the different activities of players. I am trying to explain it best.

There is a challenge assigned to different companies which have different players who perform different activities i.e. walking, and cycling. so they get some score by achieving their target from the assigned activity.

the database has hundreds of records. so the following is the query.

```
SELECT sum(score) as total_score,
                (SELECT sum(pa.distance_covered) 
                from activities a, players_score b, players_activity pa 
                where a.id=b.id_activity 
                and a.id = pa.id_activity 
                and a.atype='Read data / Sync - Walk' 
                and b.id_company=company.id
                ) as total_steps,
                (SELECT sum(pa.distance_covered) 
                from activities a, players_score b, players_activity pa 
                where a.id=b.id_activity 
                and a.id = pa.id_activity 
                and a.atype='Read data / Sync - Cycling' 
                and b.id_company=company.id
                ) as total_cycling,
                company.id_challenge 
        FROM `players_score` 
            join company on players_score.id_company=company.id 
        group by company.id_challenge 
        order by total_score DESC
```

It is taking around 215 seconds to execute.

Comment: It's 2022, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1992) as A_Long_Time`, it's long past time you adopted it. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I assume your question has nothing to do with PHP, so I removed the tag.

Comment: yes thanks for that, if anything help with it